# Python - external variable being changed by function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that squares each value in a list, returning a new list with individual values squared. I pass a list to it and it changes the original list. I'd like it to not make any changes to the original list, so that I can use it in other functions.

```
def squareset(c):
    d=c
    count = len(c)
    print(c)
    for i in range(0,(count),1):
        d[i]=d[i]**2
    return d

test = [1,2,3]
print(squareset(test))
print(test)
```

I don't have this problem with functions operating on simple variables of type int or float.

I added the d=c line trying to prevent the change to the list test, but it makes no difference. print(test) is producing the result [1,4,9] instead of [1,2,3]. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: `d=c` only assigns an alias. You should copy the list explicitly using `d=c[:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `d=c` simply makes the parameter `d` point to the same object that `c` is pointing to. Hence, every change made to `d` is made to the same object that `c` points to.

If you want to avoid changing `c` you'll have to either send a copy of the object, or make a copy of the object inside the function and use this copy.

For example, do:

```
d = [i for i in c]
```

or:

```
d = c[:]
```

instead of:

```
d = c
```

Comment: "Integers are immutable and passed by value, while objects are passed by reference": not true.  All objects are passed in exactly the same way, regardless of mutability.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations alfasin and DSM

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the list to another variable doesn't copy the list. To copy, just

```
def squareset(c):
    d=c[:]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def square(var):     
    return [x*x for x in var]  

x = [1,2,3]  
z = square(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers provided are correct I would suggest using list comprehension to square your list.

```
In [4]:

test = [1,2,3]
results = [elm**2 for elm in test]
print test
print results
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 9]
```

If you wanted a function:

```
def squareList(lst):
    return [elm**2 for elm in lst]
```